# Turning of the first ::before pseudo selector?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to design a Breadcrumb component with the following markup;

```
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" 
        class="BreadcrumbContainer">
      <a  
        href="#"
        aria-current="page" 
        class="Breadcrumb onActive" aria-current="page">Home</a>
    </nav>

    <nav aria-label="Breadcrumb" class="BreadcrumbContainer">
      <a  
        href="#"
        class="Breadcrumb" aria-current="page">Home</a>
      <a  
        href="#"
        aria-current="page" 
        class="Breadcrumb onActive" aria-current="page">Users</a>
    </nav>
```

I'm separating the `<a>` elements using the `::pseudo` selector like this:

```
.Breadcrumb::before {
  content: "/";
  padding: var(--Breadcrumb-padding);
}
```

However this will always paint the `\` in front of the first anchor element inside the `nav` element.  Is it possible to switch off the `::before` selector for the first child of N children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, by selecting breadcrumbs that aren’t first children of their parents:

```css
.Breadcrumb:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: "/";
  padding: var(--Breadcrumb-padding);
}
```

(unnecessary backwards-compatible alternative:

```css
* + .Breadcrumb::before {
  content: "/";
  padding: var(--Breadcrumb-padding);
}
```

Or by undoing it for first children:

```css
.Breadcrumb::before {
  content: "/";
  padding: var(--Breadcrumb-padding);
}

.Breadcrumb:first-child {
  content: none;
}
```